# How to build a simple chrome extension that works as a timer?

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome-extension

I'm pretty much new to coding. I'm trying to build a chrome extension that basically works as a timer. The timer will be built into the HTML popup file, and I also want users to be able to customize the settings from there. Any general tips on how to do this? Could this be possible using only javascript (+ json, html...)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a tutorial, here is one I would recommend

[How to create your first Chrome extension](https://freshman.tech/first-chrome-extension/)

Comment: i'll check it out, thank you!